# extracting dataframes from list causes column name issue

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the code and data below, the `imap` function converts every column name to `1`. How can I use the following `imap` code in such a way that the column names don't change?

Code + Data:

```
# Create a large dummy dataset
df2 = data.frame(Year = 2022, Reference_Number = seq(1,6694), c = seq(1,6694),
                  d = seq(1,6694), e = seq(1,6694), f = seq(1,6694),
                  g = seq(1,6694), h = seq(1,6694), i = seq(1,6694),
                  k = seq(1,6694), l = seq(1,6694), m = seq(1,6694),
                  n = seq(1,6694), o = seq(1,6694), p = seq(1,6694),
                  q = seq(1,6694), replace = T)

# Create a list with splitted datasets
n = 1000
lst2 = split(df2, as.integer(gl(nrow(df2), n, nrow(df2))))

# Extract dataframes 
 imap(lst2, ~ set_names(tibble(.x), .y)) %>%
        set_names(str_c("DFF", seq_along(.))) %>% 
        list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: You can do `set_names(lst2, str_c("DFF", seq_along(lst2)))` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `imap` here as the first argument of `list2env`, `x` is already a list:

```
list2env(setNames(lst2, paste0("DFF", names(lst2))), envir = globalenv())
```

Comment: I wonder why `imap` was changing the `column` names?

Comment: Because that is what you are doing. You are using `set_names` for each dataframe, with the name (`.y`) of the dataframe assigned to the columns of that dataframe. Since the name of the dataframe is 1 to 7, you get the first column of each dataframe named 1 to 7, and the other nothing.

Comment: When you iterate on the elements of your list with `imap`, `.x` in your data set is a data frame. So when you rename it with `setNames` and assign `.y` to it, it will rename all of the column names in each of your `.x`.